# Why can I subscribe to all messages in a channel but not all messages by a user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I can create a subscription to `/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages` with `ChannelMessage.Read.All` or `ChannelMessage.Read.Group`.

Because the above is not a `/teams/getAllMessages` or a `/teams/{id}/channels/getAllMessages` call then it does not fall under the Export API licensing condition so I don't need an E5 license or higher.

Whereas the endpoint `/users/{id}/chats/getallMessages` is part of the Export API and requires the elevated license.

The endpoint `/users/{user-id}/chats` is not available for application use.

So there does not seem to be anyway get subscribe to all chats by a user without having an E5 license or higher. This does not seem very symmetrical given that I can obtain all the chats for a channel without an E5 license.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to use the Application permission for [channel list message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API.  If you read the documentation page, is says that application permission version of the API is [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis) and you have to apply to Microsoft to be able to use that API.  See the [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis) page for details.

Answer (score 0):

The subscription provides information about chat messages as they are sent, while the protected API endpoint allows access to previous historical messages.